# How to make 'seat' in user input returned as a float

Tags: python

So in my short python program, I wrote:

```
print "Welcome to the Receipt Program!"
while True: 
    seat = raw_input('Enter the value for the seat: ["q to quit"] ')
    if seat is not seat.isdigit():
        print "I'm sorry but {} isn't valid. Please try again.".format(seat)
    if seat == 'q':
        break
    else:
        continue

print "*****"
total = seat.count('$')
print total
```

How do I set it so, whenever the user enters a number (a float specifically) for seat (currently not possible in my snippet), it continues with the code and then adds up all the user inputs? 
I am a beginner so apologies if it's an obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "Welcome to the Receipt Program!"
seats = []
while True: 
    seat = raw_input('Enter the value for the seat: ["q to quit"] ')
    if seat == 'q':
        break
    try:
        seats.append(float(seat))
    except ValueError:
        print "I'm sorry but {} isn't valid. Please try again.".format(seat)

print "*****"
print '$', sum(seats)
```

Note that the order in which you check the values of the input is also important (checking `'q'` first before trying to convert it to a float)

Comment: no problem @SebastianF., would you mind "accepting" the answer so as to mark this question as fulfilled?

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a try/catch statement. Here is an example of it.

```
try:
   numFloat = float(element)
except ValueError:
    print "Not a float"
```

In your case, you'd want to have it be something like this:

```
try:
    seat = float(seat)
except ValueError:
    print "I'm sorry but {} isn't valid. Please try again.".format(seat)
```

The big thing to remember when trying the float function is to assign the new value to a variable. It doesn't alter the original one.

For more information on Try/Catches, check out here - [8.3 Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to get multiple inputs from a user (in Python 2.7), each of which is a float, and then add them up?

You're right to have realized that raw_input always returns a string.  In order to turn that string into a float, you'll need to apply "float" to the input.  The thing is, if you use str.isdigit to determine whether you have a number, it'll fail every time a number has a decimal point... which is pretty likely when dealing with floats.

So your best bet, I think, is instead to catch an appropriate exception.  If you get a ValueError when invoking float(), you can indicate that there's a problem.

Here's one possible solution:

```
   total = 0
   while True:
        seat = raw_input("Enter value for the seat: ")
        if seat == 'q':
            break
        try:
            total += float(seat)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid float value; ignoring")

    print("Total is {0}".format(total))
```